# Set a random additional bit in bitstring

Tags: random, bit, bitset

Given a bitstring `s`, I am looking for a method that will set a random `0` bit in `s` to a `1` bit. Furthermore, the user should be able to specify how far "left" in `s` a bit may be set. For bonus points, the solution should still terminate if all bits are set, and it should not slow down when only a single `0` bit remains.

To give a concrete (but naive) example:

```c
for (int i = 0; ; i = (i+1) % last) {
    if (!(*v & (1 << i)) && random() > RAND_MAX/2) {
        *v |= (1 << i);
        return;
    }
}
```

There are probably much better ways of doing this, and hopefully the omniscient hive mind that is Stack Overflow can show me how.

Comment: Hmm, why the close vote? What would you like me to do to improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you counted the number of 0 bits within the specified range, picked a random number N in that range, and then flipped the Nth 0-bit, that would satisfy your "bonus" requirement.